# React functional vs classical components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Looking at the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html) regarding functional vs classical components, it seems you only need classical components if you want to create an instance that gives you access to `this` or you want the lifecycle methods. Does that mean a functional component can **only** have a render inside? If it needs to handle a click, it has to go through a `onClick` listener on the markup that links directly to its props and there's no way to go through a `handleClick` function?

```
const Type = ({onTypeClick, name}) => {
  <li
    onClick={onTypeClick.bind(null, name)}
  >
    {name}
  </li>
}
```

VS

```
const Type = React.createClass({
  handleClick (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.onTypeClick(this.props.name)
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <li onClick={handleClick}>
        {this.props.name}
      </li>
    )
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stateless component returns the result of render function, however it's just a function so it has access to stuff in closure.

```
const handleClick = (e, props) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  props.onTypeClick(props.name)
}

const Type = props => {
  // don't forget to return!
  return (
    <li onClick={event => handleClick(event, props)}>
      {props.name}
    </li>
  )
}
```